# What should I use in bash script to extract email addresses from noisy lines in file?

Tags: regex, bash, email-address

I have a file that has one email address per line. Some of them are noisy, i.e. contain junk characters before and/or after the address, e.g.

```
name.lastname@bar.com&amp;lt;mailto
&amp;lt;someone@foo.bar.baz.edu&amp;gt;
&amp;amp;lt;someone@foo.com&amp;amp;gt;Mobile
&amp;lt;nobody@nowere.com&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;ab@cd.com
no@noise.com
```

How can I extract the right address from each line of the file in a loop like this?

```
for l in `cat file_of_email_addresses`
do
     # do magic here to extract address form $l
done
```

It looks like that if I get garbage before the address then it always ends with `lt;`, and if I get it after then it always starts with `&amp`

Comment: First things first: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Then those lines are URL encoded (twice) so you should probably un-encode them. That'll get you saner output which you may be able to deal with more easily. But ultimately you need to come up with a way to figure out what part of each line is the information you care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+' file
```

Output:

```
name.lastname@bar.com
someone@foo.bar.baz.edu
someone@foo.com
nobody@nowere.com
ab@cd.com
no@noise.com
```

It's not perfect but perhaps it is sufficient for your task.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a tool that's built for pattern matching, such as `sed`.  It would help to first decode the data, as Etan suggested, but if you're willing to assume

- that the leading segments you want to remove will always end with a `;`,
- that the trailing segments you want to remove will always begin with an `&`,
- that the desired addresses will not contain either of those characters, and
- that every line will contain exactly one `@`, and that in the address,

then you can do this:

```
sed 's/^\([^@]*;\)\?\([^&;]*@[^&;]*\).*/\2/' file_of_email_addresses
```